# histogram of 2 columns in R

Tags: r, bar-chart, histogram, multiple-columns

i have data that looks like this:

```
snp=c(10139833,10139832,10139834,10139835)
code_0=c(7,7,5,4)
code_1=c(3,5,5,5)
df=data.frame(snp,code_0,code_1)
```

what i whish to do it to  plot the distribution if code_0 and code_1 : how many times does each value in  code_0 and code_1 occur: in code_0 value 7 occurs 2 times , 5 ome time anf 4 one time same for code_1 both i want in the same plot (code_0 and code_1  in different colors)
i trid to do hist function or barplot but it didnt produce the correct results or just returned an error . is there any way i can make it work in R? THANK YOU

```
 i tried this :
hist(summerized$encoding_1
+     ,
+     col = "red",
+ )
> hist(summerized$encoding_2,
+      col = "blue",
+      add = TRUE)
```

which produced :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for.

```r
library(tidyverse)
snp=c(10139833,10139832,10139834,10139835)
code_0=c(7,7,5,4)
code_1=c(3,5,5,5)
df=data.frame(snp,code_0,code_1)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = code_0:code_1,
               names_to = "code",
               values_to = "values") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=values))+
  geom_histogram()+
  facet_wrap(~code)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**Edit:**
Here the code for plotting the histogram in one plot.

```r
library(tidyverse)
snp=c(10139833,10139832,10139834,10139835)
code_0=c(7,7,5,4)
code_1=c(3,5,5,5)
df=data.frame(snp,code_0,code_1)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = code_0:code_1,
               names_to = "code",
               values_to = "values") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=values, fill=code))+
  geom_histogram()
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: is it possible to plot them together in one plot but with different colors?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. See my edit.

Comment: Of course, the looks can be adjusted easily. One of the many advantages to use ggplot2.